# Content Provider vs ORM

Tags: orm, android-contentprovider

I think, that I understand the difference between Content Providers and Databases. I have two apps, that should share data between them, so I need to use Content Provider. Yet, the amount of boilerplate code in Content Providers makes me shiver.

I have used some ORM libs previously, such as SugarORM & Requery, that seriously simplify communication with SQLite DB.

Is there some commonly used libs to simplify Content Providers code in similar way?

Is there any use of ORM libs for implementing backing DB for Content Provider?

If there is, a link for such project, combing Content Providers with backing ORM DB will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StorIO provides ORM-like functionality for an Android ContentProvider with very similar API and functionality as their SQLite library and with native RxJava support.

https://github.com/pushtorefresh/storio

Read about StorIOContentResolver at this link.

https://github.com/pushtorefresh/storio/blob/master/docs/StorIOContentResolver.md